# Differential Pair with Active Load

Tags: mosfet

I was watching one of Razavi's online videos

https://youtu.be/gjKTAx9FQHo?list=PLO4mxQzfcml_56XSGcA8ULOv7qEtZd0Hy&t=2627

At time 43:45

[image]

He considers two scenarios (part of the same differential movement):

- The gate of M1 increases. Thus, the current in the left branch increases, hence due to the current mirror, the current in the right branch increases. Thus, if we remember the Id-Vds curve of an NMOS, if current increases, Vds increaes, our drain of M2 is the output voltage. Thus, the output voltage increases. **This makes sense to me too.**
- The gate of M2 decreaeses. Thus, the current in the right branch must decrease. Razavi says that due to this, the output voltage will increase as well. **I don't understand why?** If M2 current decreases, then surely from the Id-Vds plot, Vds should fall and hence the output voltage on the drain should decrease too? Why is he saying it will increase?

Comment: This is a differential amplifier. So if M2 current decreases the M1 current will increases because the sum of a current (Id1 + Id2) must be equal to Iss (alway). Therefore if Id2 decreases the Id1 will increases and this increase in Id1 will be mirrored to the output.

Comment: So the increase in Id1 is mirrored to the output, doesn't that mean that Id2 must increase again which contradicts the fact that Id2 should have decreased?

Comment: No, Id2 will not increase again, it cannot do that because the Vgs2 decreases.  Try to read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336009/when-an-nmos-utilizes-a-pmos-current-source-load-which-transistor-is-acting-as/336044#336044 it should help you understand why Vout goes up.

Comment: Hmm. I think my concern is with the PMOS current mirror. Consider just the increase in the gate voltage of M1. If M1 gate voltage increases, the Vds of M1 should increase too. The drain of M1 is connected to the gate of M3 and M4. Thus, the Vgs of M3 and M4 has to go up. But these are PMOS current mirrors, so a higher (less negative Vgs) should mean a lower current right? But that contradicts the fact M1 gate voltage increase should have caused a current increase right?